# How to make a field displays as text without HTML code inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have a data structure like that one:

```
books = [
            {
                id: 'id1',
                content: {
                    name: '<p><span>name</span><span>1</span></p>',
                    price: 'price1',
                    date: 'd1'
                }
            },
            {
                id: 'id2',
                content: {
                    name: '<p><span>name</span><span>2</span></p>',
                    price: 'price2',
                    date: 'd2'
                }
            },
            {
                id: 'id3',
                content: {
                    name: '<p><span>name</span><span>3</span></p>',
                    price: 'price3',
                    date: 'd3'
                }
            }
        ]
```

**How to make the name field display in the external events box without HTML?**
I tried ng-bind-html-unsafe="book.content['name'] but it not works.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div id='external-events'>
  <h4 >Draggable books</h4>

     <li ng-repeat="book in books track by $index"  
             id="book.id">
          <ul class="fc-event" data-drag="true"  data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" jqyoui-draggable="{index {{$index}},placeholder:true,animate:true}">
            <li ng-bind-html-unsafe="book.content['name']"> {{book.content['name']}}</li>
            <li>{{book.content['price']}}</li>
            <li>{{book.content['date']}}<br></li>
           </ul>
      </a>
  </div>
<div id='calendar-container'>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
</body>
```

below you find the codepen created for that purpose

https://codepen.io/adier/pen/KbEpWQ?editors=1111

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `{{book.content['name']}}` from li element. You have an attribute directive `ng-bind-html-unsafe` that does the trick:

```
 <li ng-bind-html="book.content['name']"></li>
```

**Update**

replaced `ng-bind-html-unsafe` with `ng-bind-html` directive.

In controller inject `$sce` service and for each book execute `$sce.trustAsHtml(book.content.name);`

So it will look like:

```
  $scope.books.forEach(function(book) {
    book.content.name = $sce.trustAsHtml(book.content.name);
  })
```

fiddle: https://codepen.io/gudzdanil/pen/vvPJYr?editors=1111

Comment: Thank you Danil but I applied your idea but it removes the display of the name also, means I'll end up with only the 2 fields price and date nothing displayed for the name.

Comment: Thank you  very much Danil.